# How to set up GOPROXY server for offline downloading of packages

Tags: go, offline

I want to install packages for project without internet, so as i can understand i need a goprxy server for installing pre-downloaded modules, i have found such instrument (i think)

https://github.com/goproxyio/goproxy

but how can i cash packages, downloaded from github. Сan you give me step-by-step instruction or any advices, please, it's the third day of my agony.